# Is there a search limit in firebase realtime database query when working on so many nodes and does it affect performance?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For example let say i have 1000k nodes in a child

```
messages
  -messageID1
     -uID = saaa
  -messageID2
     -uID = xsss
  -messageID3
     -uID = dddd
  -messageID4
     -uID = adjd
```

If I query that uID child with `orderbychild("uID").equalTo("saaa")` will firebase give every nodes when there is a lot of childs? I mean is there a limitation about it?
Does it affects performance because of a lot of child searching even I get little of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limitations of the Firebase Realtime Database are documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits#reads).

For your specific example, let's assume you are using the following code (adapted from [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data)):

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query myMessagesQuery = databaseReference.child("messages").orderByChild("uID").equalTo("saaa");

myMessagesQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot msgSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            // TODO: handle the messages
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting messages failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadMessages:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
});
```

For such a query, the following applies:

- It will be slow if there are many messages under `/messages`
- It will be slow if there are many messages from the searched user
- It will be slow if you haven't indexed the `/messages` tree by the value of `uID`
- If the query takes longer than 15 minutes to process, the query will fail (this means that you could be waiting a while while Firebase compiles the results of your query)
- If you don't have read access to **any** of the messages, the query will fail (see [Security Rules: Rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#rules-not-filters))
- If you fetch more than 256MB worth of messages at once, the query will fail

To improve the performance of such a query, you should:

- Instruct Firebase to [create an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) based on the value of `uID` using security rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      ".indexOn": ["uID"]
    }
  }
}
```

- Paginate your query (i.e. fetch a page worth of messages, then if the user scrolls down, fetch the next page)

```
Query pageQuery = databaseReference.child("messages").orderByChild("uID").limitToFirst(20).endAt("saaa");
String mLastMessageKey = null;

// fetch the first page of results
mLoading = true; // show some loading icon
pageQuery.startAt("saaa").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String lastMessageKey = null;
        for (DataSnapshot msgSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            // TODO: handle the messages
            lastMessageKey = msgSnapshot.getKey();
        }
        mLastMessageKey = lastMessageKey;
        mLoading = false; // finished loading
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting messages failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadMessages:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
});

// later on, when you need the next page
mLoading = true;
pageQuery.startAfter("saaa", mLastMessageKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String lastMessageKey = null;
        for (DataSnapshot msgSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            // TODO: handle the messages
            lastMessageKey = msgSnapshot.getKey();
        }
        mLastMessageKey = lastMessageKey;
        mLoading = false; // finished loading
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting messages failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadMessages:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
});
```

Further reading:

- [Working with Lists of Data (Android)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data)
- [How to use a `RecyclerView` with Firebase UI](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-populate-recyclerview-with-firebase-data-using-firebaseui-in-android-studio/)

Comment: thanks for detailed and nice explanation :)).